# modal places at top of browser window with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my modal window where it is aligned to the top of the browser window. I'm thinking of moving two jQuery UI modals (ie not a lot) but this is pretty frustrating.

[image]

Any ideas what is going on? Also, why does the modal show on page load? Do I need to manually do a $('.modal').hide()?

thx

**edit 1**
here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UFuX8/

Comment: If I could see your code maybe I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/UFuX8/1/). Just had to add the "hide fade" the modal div.

Comment: cool, is there a way to center it in the viewport? It looks like an error so close to the top.

Comment: You just need to add a custom css file after the bootstrap.css and adjust the "top" and "left" properties or add some padding until it's where you want it. I say add a custom so you don't have to change bootstrap.css. This makes it easier to update. If I answered your question mark it please and if you want further help you should ask another question.